# Using Kendo Grid in MVC with AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I want to show users in a Kendo Grid. Here is my Controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Users_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            using (var rahatWeb = new RahatWebEntities())
            {
                IQueryable<User> users = rahatWeb.Users;
                DataSourceResult result = users.ToDataSourceResult(request);
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RahatWeb.Models.User>()
          .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(user => user.Id);
              columns.Bound(user => user.FirstName);
              columns.Bound(user => user.LastName);
          })
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Read(read => read.Action("Users_Read", "User"))
           )
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
)
```

The problem is that no data is shown in Grid. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: are you hitting the controller, is the controller blowing up? Is it returning data? Does it return the data in the format expected by the grid? Have you tried debugging anything?

Comment: Yes I requested the Users_Read Action manually and JSON result was returned data. When I put a breakpoint on Users_Read Action and request the Index Action then the Grid is shown normally but without any data into it.

Comment: Have you included `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` in your layout? Also, hit `F12` in your browser and check the console for any client-side errors.

Comment: @mrmashal, Thank you so much. You are correct. The problem was this. Thank you.

Comment: @MohsenJafari Good to hear that! I'll post my comment as an answer so you can mark this question accepted :)

Comment: @mrmashal, I marked your post as answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` in your layout? Also, hit `F12` in your browser and check the console for any client-side errors.